# AI software for generating 3D models based on given images

Tags: 3d, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a software that accepts human (actually sci-fi human) figure and turns it into a 3D model. I found GET3D, but it's for programmatic use (through Python) if I understand it correctly. Is there a graphical, user-friendly software for this?

Answer (score 0):

I found [3DFY](https://3dfy.ai), but I think it's proprietary. It's necessary to  contact them for a demo.

Nvidia also made [NeRF](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-ai-to-generate-3d-models-2634398c0799), but it requires a NVIDIA GPU to run.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).